# React Role Base Authorization using JWT

Tags: reactjs, jwt, authorization

In my application I am utilizing JWT and role base authorization. I am having trouble getting the role of the user to be passed down to the dashboard component so the correct data could be shown when user logs in. I also have an authUtility file, that does all the getToken and storing the Token in a cookie, which works just fine. I can show that if anyone needs to see it.

AuthProvider

```
import { createContext, useState, useMemo, useContext } from 'react';
import { retrieveToken, decodeToken } from './AuthUtils';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [token, setToken] =useState(retrieveToken)
  // Decode the JWT token to get user roles
  const decodedToken = decodeToken(token);
  const userRoles = decodedToken.role; // Extract user roles from the decoded token
  console.log("AuthProvider:" , userRoles)

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    token, 
    setToken,
    userRoles,
  }),
  [token, userRoles]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

Dashboard Layout

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getUserRoles, retrieveToken } from "../Utils/AuthUtils";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebarr from '../Components/Sidebarr';
import Navbar from '../Components/Navbar';
import classes from "../Layouts/DashboardLayout.module.css";
//import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary';

const DashboardLayout = ({ children }) => {
  // State to management
  const token = retrieveToken();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);

  const rolesFromAuthContext = getUserRoles();

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("DashboardLayout:", rolesFromAuthContext);
  },[rolesFromAuthContext]);
  


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token && window.location.pathname !== '/api/account/login') {
      navigate('/api/account/login');
    }
  }, [token, navigate]);


  return (
    <>
  
      {/* <ErrorBoundary fallback={<p>Something went wrong</p>}> */}


      <div className={classes.layout}>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <Sidebarr isSidebar={isSidebar} />
        <div>
          <Navbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
          {typeof children === 'function' && children({ userRoles: rolesFromAuthContext })}
        </div>
        </main>
      </div>
      
      {/* </ErrorBoundary> */}
    </>
      
    
  );
};

export default DashboardLayout;
```

Dashboard

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
//import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import DashboardLayout from '../Layouts/DashboardLayout';
import Header from '../Components/Header';
import { getUserRoles } from '../Utils/AuthUtils';

const Dashboard = () => {
  // State to hold user roles
  const [userRoles, setUserRoles] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch and set user roles when the component mounts
    const fetchUserRoles = async () => {
      try {
        const roles = await getUserRoles();
        setUserRoles(roles);
        console.log('Dashboard User:', roles);
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors if any
        console.error('Error fetching user roles:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchUserRoles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <DashboardLayout userRoles={userRoles}>
      {({ userRoles }) => (
        <>
          <Header
            title={userRoles.includes('Overseer') ? 'Admin Dashboard' : 'Group Leader Dashboard'}
            subtitle="Welcome to your dashboard"
          />
          {/* Additional content based on user roles can be added here */}

        </>
      )}
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```